# How do I make cmd.run answer a prompt in salt-stack?

Tags: saltstack

I've got a salt script that is being executed with `state.sls` like this:

```
salt '*' state.sls foo.bar
```

In my script I've got this:

```
foo-bar:
  cmd.run:
    - php foo.php bar --delete
    - cwd: /srv/foo
```

The `--delete` flag will cause the script to truncate a database first. My problem is that it asks a question and expects an input.

```
root@host:/srv/foo# php foo.php bar --delete
This is going to remove all data in the database. Are you sure? [y/n]:
```

Because salt doesn't know how to answer that it will time out and abort and do things that I did not intend.

The [salt docs](http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.cmd.html) on `cmd.run` did not say anything about doing this and I am not sure what to google for exactly. I know that in a Perl implementation I would use Expect to do this.

How do I tell salt to please answer with `y`?

Comment: Of course I could just add another command line option to foo.php to override the check, but let's assume there is no such option.

Comment: well, why not use expect here in your cmd.run state?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In recent versions of salt you can provide 'stdin' to cmd.run:

> ```
> A string of standard input can be specified for the command to be run using
> the ``stdin`` parameter. This can be useful in cases where sensitive
> information must be read from standard input.:
>
>     salt '*' cmd.run "grep f" stdin='one\ntwo\nthree\nfour\nfive\n'
> ```

You can create a script to do it and run it via `cmd.script` or even create a custom python module.